# Error Cannot subscript a value of type 'Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>' with an index of type 'String'

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, plist

Can someone help me? I am just reprogramming my small project from Objective-C to Swift and get the following error:

> Cannot subscript a value of type 'Dictionary' with an index of type 'String'

`eins`, `zwei`, `drei`,and  `vier` are strings that get their data from another view controller.

Objective-C Code:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *bluetoothSwitch;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *SwitchState;
    NSArray *myStrings = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:eins,zwei,drei, vier, nil];
    SwitchState = [myStrings componentsJoinedByString:mad:" | | "];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:mad:"store.plist"];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path]) {
        path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: [NSString stringWithFormat:mad:"store.plist"] ];
    }

    NSMutableDictionary *savedValue = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];
    if ([[savedValue objectForKey:SwitchState] boolValue]) {
        self.bluetoothSwitch.on = [[savedValue objectForKey:SwitchState] boolValue];
    } else {
    }
}
```

My Swift Code:

```
var eins = "Test"
var zwei = "Text"
var drei = "Test"
var vier = "Text"
var SwitchState = ""
let myStrings = [eins, zwei, drei, vier]
SwitchState = myStrings.joined(separator: " | | ")
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.applicationSupportDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
var path = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsDirectory).appendingPathComponent("store.plist").absoluteString

let fileManager = FileManager.default

if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: path) {
    path = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsDirectory).appendingPathComponent("store.plist").absoluteString
}

var savedValue = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as Dictionary?
print("Das bekommt viewdid: \(SwitchState)")
if (savedValue?[SwitchState] as? NSNumber)?.boolValue ?? false {
    bluetoothSwitch.isOn = (savedValue?[SwitchState] as? NSNumber)?.boolValue ?? false
} else {
    print("nein")
}
```

This two Lines "produce" the Errors

```
if (savedValue?[SwitchState] as? NSNumber)?.boolValue ?? false {
    bluetoothSwitch.isOn = (savedValue?[SwitchState] as? NSNumber)?.boolValue ?? false
```

Comment: Which line exactly is causing the error?

Comment: I updated the Post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please don't try to translate Objective-C code literally to Swift. There are many, many bad practices from the Swift perspective.

Basically don't use `NS...` classes in Swift if there is a native counterpart.

The error occurs because the result of a bridge cast from `NSDictionary` to `Dictionary` (without specifying the Swift types) is `Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>` which is not compatible with value type `String`

This is a real Swift version:

```
let eins = "Test"
let zwei = "Text"
let drei = "Test"
let vier = "Text"
let myStrings = [eins, zwei, drei, vier]
let switchState = myStrings.joined(separator: " | | ")
let fileManager = FileManager.default
do {
    let applicationSupportDirectory = try fileManager.url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
    let storeURL = applicationSupportDirectory.appendingPathComponent("store.plist")

    let data = try Data(contentsOf: storeURL)
    print("Das bekommt viewdid: \(switchState)")
    if let savedDictionary = try PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, format: nil) as? [String:Any],
        let savedState = savedDictionary[switchState] as? Bool {
        bluetoothSwitch.isOn = savedState
    } else {
        bluetoothSwitch.isOn = false
        print("nein")
    }
} catch { print(error) }
```

The `fileExists(atPath` check is redundant so I left it out.